# C# Sqlite InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I was unable to find a answer that helped me so here we go,

I have this function that makes a command for my SQLiteDataAdapter,
Now it works all nice in my program that uses FireBird, sadly enough im now working on a mobile framework and it doesnt seem to work here.

```
public DataTable Get(string tableName, string[] selectColumns, string[] conditionColumns,
                         object[] conditionValues)
    {
        if (conditionColumns.Length != conditionValues.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("Length of columns and values is different");
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            stringB.Append("SELECT ");
            if (selectColumns == null)
            {
                stringB.Append("* ");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < selectColumns.Length; i++)
                {
                    stringB.Append(selectColumns[i]);
                    if (i == selectColumns.Length - 1)
                    {
                        stringB.Append(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stringB.Append(", ");
                    }
                }
            }
            stringB.Append("FROM ");
            stringB.Append(tableName + " ");
            stringB.Append("WHERE (");
            for (int i = 0; i < conditionColumns.Length; i++)
            {
                stringB.Append(conditionColumns[i] + " = @" + conditionColumns[i]);
                if (i < (conditionColumns.Length - 1))
                {
                    stringB.Append(" AND ");
                }
                else
                {
                    stringB.Append(")");
                }
            }
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(stringB.ToString(), connection);

            for (int i = 0; i < conditionColumns.Length; i++)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + conditionColumns[i], (DbType)conditionValues[i]);
            }
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Database error :\r\n" + stringB + "\r\n" + e.Message, e);
        }
    }
```

Now this i my function, The error gets thrown at

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + conditionColumns[i], (DbType)conditionValues[i]);
```

with the error

> Database error :
>   SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE (animal_number = @animal_number)
>   InvalidCastException

I am not sure wat to do now, i cast DbType since its the only type it seems to accept, but still throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `conditionValues[i]` returns `object`, you can't explicitly parse it to `DbType`.

You can check your object with [`is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) to get it's compatible type or not.

For example;

```
if(conditionValues[i] is int)
{
     da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + conditionColumns[i], DbType.Int32).Value = conditionColumns[i];
}
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed it, Thanks

Comment: So quick question that als has to do with casts, i am trying to pull a item from my SQLite database like this animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]; Where BcFeedScheduleType is a public enum, Now it throws me a InvalidCastException  you have any idea why? or how to fix that?

Comment: Try something like 
animal.FeedScheduleType = (BcFeedScheduleType)Convert.ToInt32(drAnimal["feedschedule_type"]);